# How to append colored text to a macro in a loop?

Tags: macros, color, foreach, etoolbox

I'm trying to append a couple of colored numbers to a macro in a loop. That is, I'm hoping to achieve the following but with a loop:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\colorlet{color1}{red}
\colorlet{color2}{green!50!black}
\colorlet{color3}{blue}
\colorlet{color4}{black}

\begin{document}

% create a macro that would expand to
\color{color1}1 \color{color2}2 \color{color3}3
\color{color4}4 

\end{document}
```

I was able to add black numbers to a macro using the \xappto command from etoolbox as follows (I use pgf/tikz for the foreach loop):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\def\list{}
\foreach \x in {1,...,4} {
  \xappto\list{\x\ }
}
\list

\end{document}
```

Because I'm going to use these numbers a lot later, I want to make them more recognizable by assigning a different color to each number as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\colorlet{color1}{red}
\colorlet{color2}{green!50!black}
\colorlet{color3}{blue}
\colorlet{color4}{black}

\begin{document}

\def\list{}
\foreach \x in {1,...,4} {

  % Error because \x not defined outside the loop when \list is expanded
  \gappto\list{\color{color\x}}

  % Possible problem with the expansion of the \color macro
  \xappto\list{\color{color\x}}

  \xappto\list{\x\ }
}
\list

\end{document}
```

However, neither \xappto nor \gappto works in this case. If I manually expand \x \gappto works (e.g., when I replace "color\x" with "color1" within the \gappto command). Is there a way to force latex to expand \x or is there even a better way to solve the problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I haven't tried this and I haven't work with expansion in TeX in quite some time, but try adding `\noexpand` in front of `\color` with `\xappto`.

Comment: @SeanAllred, that solved the problem. Can you please write an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Just accept @egreg's answer – it's a fuller answer than I have time to write :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My impression is that this is an XY-question. Anyway, here's a way to do what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\colorlet{color1}{red}
\colorlet{color2}{green!50!black}
\colorlet{color3}{blue}
\colorlet{color4}{black}

\begin{document}

\newcommand*\tomlist{}
\foreach \x in {1,...,4} {%
  % Possible problem with the expansion of the \color macro
  \xappto\tomlist{\noexpand\color{color\x}\x\ }%
}

\noindent
{\footnotesize\texttt{\meaning\tomlist}}

\noindent
\tomlist

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note `\noexpand` that inhibits the expansion of `\color`. Also note that `\list` is a very bad name to use, because it's the command which environments such as `enumerate` and `itemize` are based on. Better using

```
\newcommand*{\tomlist}{}
```

for initializing a token list container, so you don't risk redefining something very important. Finally, note that your code has several problems, introducing blank spaces and even paragraph breaks.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a bit more robust using `\textcolor`? In the last few weeks I think the answers with `\color` has raised (or may be I'm obsessed?) when —I think— one could use `\textcolor` instead. As an example, I'm more comfortable with something like `\textrm{1} \textsf{2} \texttt{3}` than `\rmfamily 1 \sffamily 2 \ttfamily 3`.

Comment: @Manuel I haven't the slightest idea of what this is for.

Comment: Thanks for the remark with the bad macro name, the blanks and paragraphs. I was planning to use the for-loop within a tikzpicture environment, so blanks and paragraphs wouldn't matter. But for other people who might want to use it within regular text, this is very important.